# Rails App behind Wordpress using fastcgi_intercept_errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, nginx, passenger

I'm starting a migration of a WordPress website to a rails application. The migration needs to be done gradually over the next few months, so I'll need to be able to run both sites in parallel. Using fastcgi_intercept_errors on a test environment I've managed to get any 404 errors returned by WordPress to forward on to the Rails application using the following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name mydomain.com;
        root         /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html

        error_page   500 502 503 504 404 @rails;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        recursive_error_pages on;
        error_page 404 = @rails;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                include fastcgi_params;
        error_page 404 = @rails;

        }

    location @rails{
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_user user;
        rails_env development;
        root /home/user/rails_app/app/public;
    }
}
```

The problem now comes when the rails app references any /assets links they always forward back into the rails app and always load the root location of the application.

Is there any way to fix this so that assets will also be treated as part of the rails application?

Answer (score 0):

This nginx configuraton was able to do what I needed. error page directive was moved into the only the php location, and an assets location was added to redirect the default root location from the php app to the ruby application public folder.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name mydomain.com;
    root         /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        recursive_error_pages on;
        error_page 404 = @rails;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        error_page 404 = @rails;
    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        root /home/user/rails_app/app/public;
    }

    location @rails{
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_user user;
        rails_env production;
        root /home/user/rails_app/app/public;
    }
}
```